This C# code causes a System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.' I fail to see why and where the error is
When I run this code, I get

System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

when it tries to load a new form.
I tried to fix the issue on my own several times but I get the same error every time. In debugger it says that its using 37MB of memory.
This is the code of all relevant functions:
public static async Task<List<Meni>> RetrieveAll()
{
    using (var handler = new LoggingHttpClientHandler())
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Console.WriteLine("Sending request");

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/student12345/Meni/Get");

        Console.WriteLine("Request sent. Awaiting response...");

        if (Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode) == 200)
        {
            JObject menijson = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            JArray meniji = (JArray)menijson["items"];

            List<Meni> list = meniji.ToObject<List<Meni>>();

            foreach (Meni meni in list)
            {
                await meni.dodajjela();
            }

            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Greška pri prustupanju popisa menija", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

private async Task dodajjela()
{
    using (var handler = new LoggingHttpClientHandler())
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Console.WriteLine("Sending request");

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/student12345/Meni/GetRelated?men={this.id_menija}");

        Console.WriteLine("Request sent. Awaiting response...");

        if (Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode) == 200)
        {
            JObject jelajson = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            JArray jela = (JArray)jelajson["items"];

            foreach (var jel in jela)
            {
                var resp =  await Jela.Retrieve(jel["idjela"].ToString());
                this.jelas.Add(resp);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<Jela> Retrieve(string id)
{
    using (var handler = new LoggingHttpClientHandler())
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Console.WriteLine("Sending request");

        var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/student12345/Meni/Jelo?je={id}");

        Console.WriteLine("Request sent. Awaiting response...");

        if (Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode) == 200)
        {
            JObject jelajson = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            jelajson.Remove("links");
            return CreateObj(jelajson);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

private static Jela CreateObj(JObject objekt)
{
     Image slikajelo = null;

     using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
     {
         byte[] slikabiteovi = client.DownloadData($"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/student12345/Meni/image?br={objekt.Property("id_jelo").Value.ToString()}");

         using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(slikabiteovi))
         {
             slikajelo = Image.FromStream(ms);
         }
     }

     Jela jelo = new Jela
     {
         id_jela = objekt.Property("id_jelo").Value.ToString(),
         slika= slikajelo,
         ime_jela= objekt.Property("ime_jela").Value.ToString()
     };
                  
     return jelo;
}


Probably an immage format error - nothing to do with memory..

If you really are running out of memory, first eliminate all your intermediate objects, specifically the response string await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() and the menijson JTkoken hierarchy.  Deserialize directly from the response stream to your final data model.  Beyond that we probably need to see a [mcve] including your Meni data model and a sample JSON response.

Besides that, you cannot do this: using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(slikabiteovi)) { }, i.e., dispose of the Stream that generates the Image. You're killing your Image objects, any error can come out of that after. The Stream is disposed along with the bitmap data when you dispose of the images after use

The number of HttpClient instances you use is definitely bad, you should only use one (or a few) and reuse them.

See this answer. As @TaW pointed out it might be unsupported image format.

How many images are you downloading?  How big is each one?

Talk us through why you need the image in an Image object.

It seems that it might actually be because of what @Jimi pointed out above: you are closing Stream which is supposed to be kept opened and I suspect that Image than can throw (misleading) out of memory exception because of that. The full exception stack trace might shed more light on the root of the problem (which method throws it?)

Please share the exact url you are downloading from.

In debugger it says that its using 37MB of memory. What is the value of Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 just prior to when it fails?

Side note: you are missing some usings there.

Image class implements IDisposable - so calling Dispose on it to accelerate the cleanup of the underlying unmanaged resource is wise (the GC will likely clean it up eventually - but not in a fast / deterministic way).
You will need to manually dispose the Image it after you use it because if you keep creating these objects, the memory might run out before the GC can automatically clean it up.
So for example, in your code you will need to dispose your images using slikajelo.Dispose() or slika.Dispose() at some point in your program after you use your CreateObj method. Not sure how your Jela class looks like but you could even dispose that if you have a dispose() method defined in that class.
Please refer the Image.Dispose documentation for more details.

Yeah, the out of memory comes from 'System.Drawing.dll' where the Image class is defined.

Image is managed object which is cleared by GC automatically (which also releases underlying unmanaged resources). Calling Dispose just forces this to happen immediately upon Dispose invocation instead of waiting for GC to kick in.

@Ed'ka Don't count on that when you deal with disposable objects and especially the Graphics ones. Some badly written code that floods the memory with disposable objects (images, fonts, brushes, pens...etc.) might leave no resources at all for the GC itself to do its job. The IDisposable interface exists for a good reason and helps the GC to collect the disposed objects without any further lengthy checking. That does matter at the critical points. Also, .Dispose does not force the GC to do anything if the current memory state is OK.

@Jimi Yes, it will be GC-ed eventually. It will just take two GC cycles to do it (since it will be placed into finalization queue). Calling Dispose will make Image to release unmanaged resource immediately (so one should do it) but not calling it should not lead to out of memory either since GC will take care of it, provided that Image correctly disposes unmanaged resources in Finalize method, which I believe it does.
